# is there any database transaction mechanism in MFC/C++?

Tags: c++, database, mfc, transactions

I want to make sure that if any error occurs during the database processing phase, program will know it need to roll back the whole process.

any good ORM in MFC/C++ for doing this ?

Comment: doesn't this depend on the database you are using? Access for example does not support transactions, MySQL does - depending on the DB engine, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MFC _ConnectionPtr object has BeginTrans, CommitTrans and RollbackTrans methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675942(VS.85).aspx

I wouldn't call it good though, you'd need to wrap it.

Comment: in C++ - use RAII-Classes to wrap them. Constructor begins the transaction, destructor rollsback if no commit was applied before destruction.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with ORM. You want basic transaction functionality

If you're using MFC, then most likely you're working with your database either via `CDatabase` (ODBC), `CDaoWorkspace`/`CDaoDatabase` (DAO), or `CDataConnection`/`CSession` (OLE DB). If so, you should use `CDatabase::Rollback`, `CDaoWorkspace::Rollback`, or `CSession::Abort`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting to a transactional database, like SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Firebird, some of MySQL's data engines, etc. then they will have an API for transactions.  Similarly, some non-SQL databases also have transactional semantics and an associated API (like Berkeley DB).  Since you don't mention what database you're using, I really don't know what else to say.

Answer (score 0):

Debea Database Library is an ORM for C++ - http://debea.net/